# Comparing dates in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, date, compare

I am a beginning programmer in C# and asp.net. I am busy trying to create a Hotel application. Where somebody is able to book for example an 8 day vacation. But now I need to add a formula that calculates the price. The method I am writing is getting the price per night of the room from the database. And the days that the person is staying is entered in the view and passed down to the controller.So I want to calculate the price inside the controller. But now I have a problem cause the price of staying in the hotel is higher in the high-season than in the low-season. So the prices differs per day. But now I do not really now how to compare the dates so I am able to give an accurate total price.

I have looked over some threads on stack overflow and they often advice to use Timespan to compare dates. But I was wondering is Timespan the best solution for me? Cause for my project the price should flow and not be fixed. For example it should not be like 28 May - 10 July is €120 euro per night but more like 28 May €109, 29 May €112, 30 May €113 - 9 July €127, 10 July 130.

If I would succeed in creating a different price per day then the last thing should not be that hard I hope. The price of each date should be added to each other so I will have the total price.

So my questions are:

- Is the best way to compare dates Timespan?
- Is there an easy way to calculate this? I would not like fixed dates.
- Are there any good tutorials for this?

Comment: Just have  start and end date for your season and check if your booking date falls in that range like `if(bookingDate >= seasonStartDate && bookingDate <= seasonEndDate)`

Comment: How do you plan to store the prices?  I'd suggest in a DB and then you can write a query that will calculate the price based on start and end dates.

Comment: I would get the price for each day one-by-one and then add them up.  It would be a lot simpler than messing with timespans and edge cases and since there are only a few days, the performance hit is insignificant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just compare each Date object between the start and end dates to see if it falls within a defined range to determine the rate, and sum them as I go.

This is probably overkill for you, but I would encapsulate the different 'seasons' and their rates in a class, and add a method to the class that will determine if a date falls within that 'season'. This will simplify the other methods.

Then I would create a method that, given a single date, will return the rate for that date.

Finally, I would calculate the total price by calling the GetRate() method for each day between the client's start date (inclusive) and end date (exclusive).

Here's a sample of how I would do it. First, the class to hold a 'season'

```
public class Season
{
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public int Rate { get; set; }

    public bool ContainsDate(DateTime date)
    {
        // Assumption: Year is ignored - seasons are considered 
        //             to start and end on the same date each year
        //
        // Rules: (remember a season may start in Dec and end in Jan,
        //         so you cant just check if the date is greater than
        //         the start or less than the end!)
        // 
        // 1. If the start and end month are the same,
        //    return true if the month is equal to start (or end) month
        //    AND the day is between start and end days.
        // 2. If the date is in the same month as the start month, 
        //    return true if the day is greater than or equal to start day.
        // 3. If the date is in the same month as the end month, 
        //    return true if the day is less than or equal to end day.
        // 4. If the StartMonth is less than the EndMonth, 
        //    return true if the month is between them.
        // 5. Otherwise, return true if month is NOT between them.

        if (StartDate.Month == EndDate.Month)
            return date.Month == StartDate.Month &&
                   date.Day >= StartDate.Day &&
                   date.Day <= EndDate.Day;

        if (date.Month == StartDate.Month)
            return date.Day >= StartDate.Day;

        if (date.Month == EndDate.Month)
            return date.Day <= EndDate.Day;

        if (StartDate.Month <= EndDate.Month)
            return date.Month > StartDate.Month && date.Month < EndDate.Month;

        return date.Month < EndDate.Month || date.Month > StartDate.Month;
    }
}
```

Next, a method that will calculate the rate for a specific date:

```
public static int GetRate(DateTime date)
{
    // Normally these 'seasons' and rates would not be hard coded here
    const int offSeasonRate = 125;

    var winterSeason = new Season
    {
        StartDate = DateTime.Parse("November 15"), 
        EndDate = DateTime.Parse("January 12"), 
        Rate = 150
    };

    var springSeason = new Season
    {
        StartDate = DateTime.Parse("May 20"), 
        EndDate = DateTime.Parse("June 15"), 
        Rate = 140
    };

    var summerSeason = new Season
    {
        StartDate = DateTime.Parse("July 10"), 
        EndDate = DateTime.Parse("August 31"), 
        Rate = 170
    };

    // Create a list of all the seasons
    var seasons = new List<Season> {winterSeason, springSeason, summerSeason};

    // Loop through all the seasons and see if this date is in one of them
    foreach (var season in seasons)
    {
        if (season.ContainsDate(date))
        {
            // Note: depending on your implementation, Rate could be a multiplier
            // in which case you would return (offSeasonRate * season.Rate);
            return season.Rate;
        }
    }

    // If we get this far, the date was not in a 'season'
    return offSeasonRate;
}
```

Finally, here is the method that gets the total price for a date range:

```
var startDate = DateTime.Today;
var endDate = startDate.AddDays(2);
var price = 0;

// Sum the rates for each day between 
// start date (inclusive) and end date (exclusive).
for (var curDate = startDate; curDate < endDate; curDate = curDate.AddDays(1))
{
    price += GetRate(curDate);
}

Console.WriteLine("The total cost from {0} to {1} is: €{2}", 
    startDate, endDate, price);
```